# Listing the archives from Amazon Glacier Vault in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

There is easy way to retrieve Amazon Glacier metadata in C#, by using the AmazonGlacierClient class. However, there is no straight forward way to retrieve list of archives in vault. Is this even possible?

Also, is there any way for retrieving archive metadata (for example name and extension)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible by downloading the vault inventory.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-inventory.html

Comment: I tried the sample code for this and nothing happened after 4 hours. Did you get this working?

Comment: After about 4 hours a notification from amazon pushed to the SNS you provided it's topic when you initiate the job, this notification contains the job processing result then you can download the job output in separate request.

Also you can check the job status manually.

Comment: So for example, what do you put in the parameter for SNS Topic?